# Get user notes in a item to which he doesnt have access

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

Situation 
I have a list on which person X will place an item. This will trigger a workflow.
In this workflow I want to address person Y with a question about the item. Person Y may not alter or see the full item.

How can I make a email/field/task or other list were person Y can answer the question and this answer is placed in the Original item by the workflow.
Preferably as easy as possible for person Y (no Edit buttons etc, just a field and insert button).

Answer (score 0):

Add two fields in the list: Status (text) and Assigned to(user). Initially, they will be empty. In the workflow, check if they are empty. If yes, fill the status and assigned to columns and send a link to Edit / Display form of that item. In display / edit forms, make a check for both of these fields. If both satisfy the condition, hide the other fields and show the required fields using jQuery / CSR. After the AssignedTo user fills the information, update to list using REST api / JSOM. If they don't satisfy, show a message or make the form read only.